# Android Status Bar Interfering with Ionic App

Tags: android, ionic-framework

When emulating on an android phone the bottom status bar is not being taken into consideration when the main view is being displayed, thus hiding app components at the very bottom.

I've read I can include a `android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”` somewhere but I'm not exactly sure where I could add this in order to test.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.